# Laser X 88016 remove beeping noise

Tags: pcb, audio

I have bought a [Laser X 88016](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MEG7QRK) two player set gaming device.

When turned, the device on makes an annoying beeping noise every three seconds, no matter what. (As you can imagine you can't really stealth in the game due to the noise.)

Looking on the internet yielded no satisfactory result. The only [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-fEQLFa0dE) I got was to cut out the buzzer that makes the noise. This way all the other sound effects will be lost, too. (The device can be used with a headset, but the beeping noise will still persist from the weapon part where the buzzer is located.)

I have no experience or education to understand the electronics behind this device. My question is:
**Is is possible for myself at home to disable the beeping sound?**

I have access to basic equipment if needed.

The PCB of the receiver which I managed to disassemble can be seen here:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Most likely, the black blob at the top is some kind of microcontroller that also generates all the sounds. Disabling only 1 particular sound would require modifiying the software. This is most likely impossible due to unavailability of source code and the fact that it's probably a one time programmable device anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply, this is useful enough. Have nice holidays!

Comment: Since only you wrote a comment, post this as an answer, I'll gladly mark it as accepted. Also based on your answer, my only real solution would be to reverse engineer the software and pcb, if I am correct, which would be very time exhaustive since I only know the basics of basics.

Comment: My plan is to cut the signal wires going to speaker inside blaster then splice a headphone jack plug pigtail onto speaker leads(beeping noise is not present in Headphone signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black blob at the top is probably some kind of micro controller that also generates all the sounds. Disabling only 1 particular sound would require modifying the software. This is most likely impossible due to unavailability of source code and the fact that it is probably a one time only programmable device anyway.